# mono requirements

Tags: mono, operating-system

So what are mono´s requirements to an operating system or hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [FAQ](http://mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical) will probably tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: yes i´ve been there before, but i could used some more detailed info like minimum Kernel version, what about VxWorks, must it be real time os. How many memory does mono need. Maybe i try to reach some support.